# What is basic difference between UploadData and DownloadString in asp.net webclient?

Tags: asp.net, webclient, downloadstring, webclient.uploaddata

I am new to `webclient`.
I have seen some examples to `POST` data to a `server`. I am worrying which one to be used over other. Can any one please tell me what to use when?

**UploadData:**

```
system.net.webclient.uploaddata(uri, byte[]);
```

**DownloadString:**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var result = client.DownloadString(someurl);
```

Suggestions welcome..!

Answer (score 1):

the basic difference between both - Uploaddata method can be used to retrieve data based on provided inputs from specified URI(address of service) while DownloadString can be used to retrieve data without sending any inputs parameters.